# При сохранении или удалении записи возникает ошибка

Tags: wordpress, seo, wordpress-плагины

При Удалении или добавлении в черновик записи появляется этот список в чем может быть проблема?

Warning: filesize(): stat failed for /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/3468860р.png in /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/builders/indexable-link-builder.php on line 287

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/builders/indexable-link-builder.php:287) in /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-admin/post.php on line 231

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/builders/indexable-link-builder.php:287) in /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1296

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/src/builders/indexable-link-builder.php:287) in /home/host1693331/host1693331.hostland.pro/htdocs/www/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1299

```
if ( $is_image && $model->target_post_id ) {
        list( , $width, $height ) = \wp_get_attachment_image_src( $model->target_post_id, 'full' );

        $model->width  = $width;
        $model->height = $height;
        $model->size   = \filesize( \get_attached_file( $model->target_post_id ) );
    }
```

в этой строке проблема `$model->size   = \filesize( \get_attached_file( $model->target_post_id ) );`

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/Cannot_modify_header_information

Comment: Это немного не то. Дело не в Этом.